# How can I extract a function from lists

Tags: numpy, scipy

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = [0.999,0.9995, 0.9999,0.99993, 0.99995,0.99998, 0.99999]
y = [30, 50, 80, 120, 150, 400, 500]

plt.plot(x,y,'o')
```

Hello!

I want to extract a mathmatical function from two lists by using scipy or something.

is there a way?

Comment: use this import : `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpolate your data using `scipy`

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

x = [0.999,0.9995, 0.9999,0.99993, 0.99995,0.99998, 0.99999]
y = [30, 50, 80, 120, 150, 400, 500]
x_new = np.linspace(0.999,1,40)

fnc = interpolate.interp1d(x,y,fill_value='extrapolate')
y_new = fnc(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o',x_new,y_new)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you have a function you'd like to fit it to, you can explore [curve fitting](http://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/~robitaille/PY4SCI_SS_2014/_static/15.%20Fitting%20models%20to%20data.html)